# Typescript: what Index signature not found means?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Instance {
    [param: string]: string;
}

const checkRequiredProps = (instance: Instance, requiredProps: string[]) => {
    const props = requiredProps.filter((prop: string) => {
        return !instance[prop];
    });

    console.log(props);
};
```

```
interface IHuman {
    name: string;
}

class Test {
    private readonly _name: string;

    constructor(human: IHuman = {} as IHuman) {
        checkRequiredProps(human, ['name']);
        this._name = human.name;
    }

    public get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }
}

const test = new Test({ name: 'loki' });
```

[image]

I have 2 types `Instance` which is a simple object with arbitrary key-value pairs. and there is `IHuman` which contains `name` property. I am trying to pass `IHuman` to a function that accepts `Instance`. I got the error as shown in the image.

But when I change the `IHuman` from interface to a `type`. the error is gone.

```
type IHuman = {
    name: string;
}
```

What is the error about and why is it gone in the second case. Is there a better way to type `Instance`. I want `Instance` to be the general type that can accept any object. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because `interface`s in TypeScript can't be duck typed as other, more generic interfaces.  You could have `IHuman` extend `Instance` to make it work, but you probably don't want to do that for every interface you want to run `checkRequiredProps` on.

**EDIT**: From the comments below, the function signature of `checkRequiredProps` is changed to an object with keys that are `string`s and can be `any` type.  This will still allow arrays in, but strings, booleans, `null`, and `undefined` should not be able to be passed in.

```
const checkRequiredProps = (instance: {[key: string]: any}, requiredProps: string[]) => {
    const props = requiredProps.filter((prop) => {
        return !instance[prop];
    });

    console.log(props);
};

interface IHuman {
    name: string;
}

interface IWerewolf {
    name: string;
}

class Test {
    private readonly _name: string;

    constructor(human: IHuman = {} as IHuman, werewolf: IWerewolf = {} as IWerewolf) {
        checkRequiredProps(human, ['name']);
        checkRequiredProps(werewolf, ['name']);
        this._name = human.name;
    }

    public get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }
}

const test = new Test({ name: 'loki' }, { name: 'wolfington' });
```

Added another `interface` for making sure werewolves are treated with the same rights as humans.

Comment: hey this code has an error. try it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.htm

Comment: Ah, thanks for calling that out!  I had just pasted it into WebStorm and it seemed ok, there.  I'll update my answer with a change that should hopefully suffice!

Comment: Your `checkRequiredProps` is not generic, you effectively have `instance: any`, `T` is misleading there and does not add anything.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I'll move the inner cast to the function signature so it's clear it accepts an object with keys of type `string`.  That way it's not completely `any` typed in generic clothing.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: any comments on my solution?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57083156/4127542

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkRequiredProps = <I, P extends keyof I>(instance: I, requiredProps: P[]) => {
    const props = requiredProps.filter((prop) => {
      return !instance[prop];
    });

    console.log(props);
};

interface IHuman {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface IWerewolf {
    name: string;
}

class Test {
    private readonly _name: string;

    constructor(human: IHuman = {} as IHuman, werewolf: IWerewolf = {} as IHuman) {
        checkRequiredProps(human, ['name', 'age']);
        checkRequiredProps(werewolf, ['name']);
        this._name = human.name;
    }

    public get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }
}

const test = new Test({ name: 'loki', age: 10 }, { name: 'wolfington' });
```